# Which is the correct shorthand - "regex" or "regexp"

Tags: regex, terminology

Most of us computer programmers are pretty obsessed about correct terminology. I certainly am, especially because sometimes changing just one character in a word can drastically change its meaning.

So... what is the correct shorthand for "regular expression"? Is it "regex" or "regexp"? On the internet I see both uses, although "regex" seems to be more popular, and the tag list here on SO also includes just "regex". But plenty of people also use "regexp" in their questions.

Comment: I believe that the one which is easiest to pronounce wins - "regex" beats "regexp" there by a mile. This happens all the time in human languages. That is just my opinion.

Comment: I have honestly never seen it referred to as regexp. Not once in my entire life before this instant.

Comment: It's common in Perl-land to call them regexp and regex, with multiples being regexes or regexen - TMTOWTDI .  :)

Comment: and is it pronounced reg-ex, or rej-ex?

Comment: @SqlACID I would like to know if it is reg-ex or rej-ex as well...

Comment: @Anthony, clearly you haven't done much JS programming.

Comment: @Artefacto - Actually, I thought one was gramatically correct and the other wasn't. Or maybe someone had defined it somewhere in some standard. Anyways, I thought that there really is a "correct" version here, and that this isn't subjective.

Comment: Please note that *neither* "regex" nor "regexp" is shorthand for "regular expression". The *whole reason* why we call those things "regexes" or "regexen" or "regexps" is because they are *not* regular expressions. Far from it.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag - ok, so maybe I used the word "shorthand" incorrectly. Could you help me with that as well then?

Comment: Historically, you are of course correct. The word "regex" is a contraction of the words "regular expression". But the *things* that we call regular expressions are completely different than the things we call regex. For example: regular expressions are designed to be extremely simple and elegant. I can write down the full syntax and semantics of regular expressions in 4 lines each. In fact, I don't even need full lines, just 4 bullet points each are enough. In contrast, the syntax for regexp literals in the ECMAScript5 specification takes up an entire page ...

Comment: ... and the semantics even have their own *chapter* of twenty(!) pages. And ECMAScript5 regexps aren't even that powerful, Perl5's or Oniguruma's regexes are *much more* complex.

Comment: This reminds me of another 'important' question: "Is it pronounced 'car' or 'char'?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology and not programming.

Comment: In the [original memo](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/qedman.html) of QED (1970), where Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson introduced the brand new feature of regular expressions (new in the context of text editing, that is), they wrote: **'In subsequent discussion, "<regexp>" will denote a regular expression.'**... So, by today's standards, they were wrong, but just the other way around, unlike with their `creat` in UNIX. ;)

Comment: For a while, I’ve preferred “regexp” in all of my writing for the reason that @Sz brings up (and I like symmetry: RegExp)… until I came across [Regular Expressions, Aren’t](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/448/regular-expressions-arent/486#486), wherein it’s pointed out that “regex” need not necessarily mean “Regular Expression” *proper* — indeed, it may even be incorrect (to mathematicians at least) to so employ the term, depending upon context — but rather one of the **Ex**tended forms with which many programmers are familiar. Specificity *is* important, so “regex” it is for me.

Comment: I tend to prefer "regex" by consistency with "redex", which stands for "reducible expression".  *No one* would ever refer to a "redexp", "redex" is very well established.

Comment: @akim - ... What's a redex? -_-

Comment: A reducible expression is something on which you can perform a reduction, i.e., apply one transformation/rewriting allowed in a given formal system.  In a system coding arithmetics `1+2` and `2+3` would be redexes of `1+2+3`, but `1`, `2` and `3` are not. In [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), the main type of reducible expressions is called a β-redex, and roughly corresponds to performing a function call.

Answer (score 666, accepted):

```
/regexp?/
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `/regexp{0,1}/`?

Comment: @Igor: that's precisely what `?` means in a regular expression, `{0,1}`. True, some regexp? engines don't support the question mark but they suck ;-) Anyway Perl does, and it's the closest thing to a "standard" for regular expression syntax.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Azat Yes, it is. It perfectly says whichever is ok!

Answer (score 74):

[Googlefight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=regex&word2=regexp) says *regex* wins, 685000 to 289000  (which is about 2.37:1).

Also, *regexp* is strange to say out loud because there are so few (if any?) words that end in a "-ksp" sound, but there are plenty of words that end in a "-ecks" sound.

Comment: In World of Warcraft, people go out to gain some "exp" (short for "experience points"). So saying "exp" is neither hard nor does it sound weird. It is all simply a matter of how used the speaker is to that word.

Comment: I'd pronounce "exp" as "ex-pee" - I don't play WoW...

Comment: I like the answer, but I prefer the pronounciation of **regexp**. Saying simply **regex** is lacking, because it does not account all the consonants in the beginning.  Usually abbreviations should do that, eg. *constant* should be *const*, not *con*.

Comment: @Shi Warcraft players almost always read or write "exp".

Answer (score 31):

They are both OK.  "regex" is more common, but "regexp" has been used more widely than the other answers here indicate.  Some examples:

- Henry Spencer referred to his famous library as "regexp" as early as 1986. (http://groups.google.com/group/mod.sources/msg/ab37bf1ead7209ec?)
- The Jargon File listed "regexp (also regex, reg-ex)" as early as 1991. (http://groups.google.com/group/misc.misc/msg/e75ca9cb78220ea0?)
- JavaScript and Ruby both have Regexp or RegExp in their standard libraries.

Comment: Man regexp on my mac turns up a Tcl man page. Hmmm...maybe that's not an endorsement.

Answer (score 17):

`regex` is shorter; therefore, better :) Also, it is easier to pronounce.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted shorthand is "regex".

"Regexp" is only used, in my experience, in the context of Javascript where the object representing a regular expression is actually called `RegExp`.

Comment: and in emacs.  The function for finding a regular expression is `isearch-forward-regexp`, etc.

Comment: ECMAScript in general - even ActionScript calls it `RegExp`

Comment: Ruby too: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Comment: Well, in the [original memo](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/qedman.html) of QED, where Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson introduced the brand new feature of regular expressions (in the context of text editing), they wrote: *"In subsequent discussion, "<regexp>" will denote a regular expression."*

Answer (score 7):

I think "regex" is more common (e.g., Java package `java.util.regex`).  If 10,000 Elvis fans can't be wrong, then I'd vote for that on the strength of numbers.

Comment: And in .NET it is `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

Comment: It's also `Regex` in Swift.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

> In computing, regular expressions,
>   also referred to as regex or regexp,
>   ...

Comment: Who the hell votes up a quote from Wikipedia?!?

Comment: @Adam Harte: Who the heck votes up rhetorical questions?

Comment: @Andrew haha, it's actually a "question statement question"

Answer (score 6):

"regex" is more common and what is used in the Perl FAQ. Google gives 4.5 million hits for "regex" and 3.6 million for "regexp." Wikipedia uses both.

What do you prefer? I don't think anyone will think of you badly if you use them interchangeably.

Comment: Interestingly enough "perldoc perlre" (that describes regular expressions in perl), says "regex" everywhere but references "Regexp Quote-Like Operators" in perlop. "perldoc perlop" is a little confused ans says both, though mostly "regex". "perl -le 'print ref(qr/x/)'" prints out "Regexp". So perl is confused, I'd say.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's time to quit thinking in terms of shorthands or abbreviations.  The regexes that we use in our daily tasks are a different breed entirely from the regular expressions of computer science or formal language theory.  This is why Larry Wall and other prominent members of the Perl community have preferred "regex" for years: to call them RegExp or RegEx, or even RE, suggests a relationship that no longer applies.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's "regex", this is based on my own experience, how I've heard it, and the community discussion here.

I can't find it at the moment, but this discussion was on meta over tags on SO, which is why this is the [only question tagged "regexp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp), the rest (8441 and counting) are tagged ["regex"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

---

Just a side thought here: does it *matter* which is "correct?" Think about the purpose here, why do you use any word?  To communicate.  To a certain degree, it doesn't matter what's correct or not, it matters which one you *can effectively communicate to more people*.  I would say you could easily argue to use an incorrect term, if that's what the majority of your audience uses, since communication is your goal.

Comment: The reason there are no questions tagged "regexp" is because some of us keep removing that tag or replacing it with "regex" (as I just did here).  We don't need two tags with the same meaning, and "regex" has the edge in terms of users' preferences (though that may be just because it's shorter).

Comment: @Alan - yes, but don't you think that in this case "regexp" was ALSO a good choice, because the question is about comparing the two?

Comment: @Vlix- You could just as easily argue that *neither* tag is appropriate, since the question is really about terminology, not regexes.  But the responses seem to show that "regex" is the winner anyway, so why don't we just stick with that?

Comment: UPDATE: This Q/A ran its course before the "tag synonyms" feature was implemented here at StackOverflow.  Now tags like `regexp` and `regular-expression` are automatically converted to `regex`.

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine for written discourse, though you probably don't want to say "regexp" out loud too often ;)

For use in code, I think regexp is probably clearer. Especially if you use capitalization such as RegEx/RegExp. An Ex suffix is often used to indicate an extended version of a simpler function... i.e. CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx in the Windows API, so RegExp might be a little less ambiguous as far as readability of code goes.

Answer (score 3):

I have also heard/read:

`reg-exp`

And some people prefer `regex` because the plural `regexes` is "nicer"! (in addition to reasons explained by other answers).

.NET `regex` : `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

JavaScript `regexp` : `RegExp`

Comment: Or n.pl. Regexen.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer "re", but it depends on the language.  JavaScript lists it as "RegExp", whereas most other languages just call it "RegEx."

When googling, go with the shorter version.  But in forums, use "re" ;)